# Query performance in spark-submit vs hive shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I am having hard time debugging why a simple query against hive external table (dynamodb backed) is taking north of 10 minutes via spark-submit and it only takes 4 seconds in hive shell.

Hive External Table that refers to a Dynamodb table say Employee[id, name, ssn, dept].  id is the partition key and ssn is the range key.

Using aws emr  5.29, spark, hive, tez, hadoop. 1 master, 4 core, m5.l

in hive shell:  `select name, dept, ssn from employee here id='123/ABC/X12I'` returns results in 4 seconds.

Now, lets say i have the following code in code.py (ignoring the imports)

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
data=spark.sql("select name, dept, ssn from employee here id='123/ABC/X12I'")
# print data or get length
```

I submit the above on the master node as:

`spark-submit --jars /pathto/emr-ddb-hive.jar, /pathto/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar code.py`

The above spark submit takes a long time 14+ minutes.  I am not sure which parameter needs to be tweaked or set to get better response time.

In hive shell I did a `SET`; to view the parameters that hive shell is using and there are a gazillion.

I also tried a boto3 dynamodb way of searching and it is way faster than my simple py sql to spark-submit.

I am missing fundamentals...Any idea or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing an aggregation when I was trying to print by doing a **collect()** .  I read about it but, did not realize that it was that bad (timing wise).  I also did end up doing some more experiments like **take(n)** **limit 1**.